# How to download a file using dynamic download path name using FileChooser

Tags: java, swing, filechooser

I have a filechooser:

```
JFrame parentFrame = new JFrame();
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

fileChooser.setDialogTitle(txtPushCode.getText());   

int userSelection = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(parentFrame);

if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
{
    File fileToSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    System.out.println("Save as file: " + fileToSave.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

and a downloadIcon method:

```
public boolean downloadIconUrl(String url) 
{
   try 
   {
      String fileName = "C:\\android\\tempcolor\\icon.png"; 

      URL link = new URL(url); // The file that you want to download

      InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
      ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      int n = 0;
      while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) 
      {
         out.write(buf, 0, n);
      }
      out.close();
      in.close();
      byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
      fos.write(response);
      fos.close();

      System.out.println("Icon downloaded");

   } 
   catch (IOException ex) 
   {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }

   return true;
```

But as you can see, it downloads only to "C:\android\tempcolor\icon.png". I want to download it to path where I chose in FileChooser with the name and extension I choose.
In short, how can I use dynamic file path names in where ever I want in my applications?

Comment: Have you considered passing `fileName` as a parameter to the `downloadIcon` method?

Comment: ..what dies this have to do with SWT?

Comment: so right now, you are hard coding the destination path, but you need to use FileChooser to specify a destination path, use FileChooser with JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES or JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY so that you select the destination path.

Comment: yes, I know I'm giving a static path to downloaded file. I want to download to a place where I chose with the FileChooser. I think I must change the "String fileName" and "FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);" codes to work with FileChooser but I couldn't found out